# Rails 3: Handling privacy features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Part of my app is responsible for writing to a feed all the user actions. However, I'd like to allow the user to control his privacy features (stop sending to the feed, only send some actions, etc).

What is the best way to do that? Shall I use Cancan or something similar and give roles to different privacy options?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could use CanCan but, in my opinion, using simple conditional statements would be much simpler.

I would do something along the lines of:

```
def write_to_feed(user, action)
  unless user.private?
    unless user.private_action? action
      # Write to feed
    end
  end
end

write_to_feed @user, :post
write_to_feed @user, :comment
```